# October Cms - Using custom validation written in vanilla Js (Ajax) to validate forms (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, laravel, octobercms

I'm currently trying to migrate a static website to October CMS, but am facing problems with my contact form that is using a validation script written in Vanilla JS (ajax) -> [mandala.morgana-design.com/contacto](http://mandala.morgana-design.com/contacto#form). Is it possible to call out the custom validation on submit, without the usage of of the ajax framework that came with OctoberCMS? There are certain validations that are logical to the current form I'm developing (for example, making a field mandatory on select radio button, including live validation).

I'm quite new to OctoberCMS and laravel, any assistance or advice I can receive is really appreciated!

Comment: Hi, i don't know what is the problem, just include your custom javascript and do your custom validations, OctoberCms does not force you to use the ajax fremework

Comment: Hi OsDev, you're right. I did manage to figure out the framework and applied my custom validation to the form. Thank you.